# Oracle returning result from dynamic SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi I am trying to return a value from Oracle using dynamic SQL.  I am getting an error SQL command not properly ended.  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  Here is the latest code I've tried:

```
PROCEDURE get_record_counts
AS
v_EXT_RECCOUNT   VARCHAR2(05) := '0';
BEGIN

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*)  from ' ||  r_cls.EXT_TABLE ||  ' RETURN v_EXT_RECCOUNT into v_EXT_RECCOUNT ';


END  get_record_counts;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) from ' || r_cls.ext_table
   INTO v_ext_reccount
```

assuming that `r_cls.ext_table` resolves to a `varchar2` variable that contains a table name that the caller has appropriate permissions on.  In the snippet you posted, that is not a valid variable name but I'm guessing that there is more code that you've removed that declares that variable.

Comment: That did the trick.  I was trying to add the "into" portion in the quotes of the execute immediate.  Thanks!